# Since updating to firebase-functions 2.0.5, cannot deploy functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

firebase-functions: 2.0.5

firebase-tools: 4.2.1

firebase-admin: 6.0.0

node: 6.11.5

npm: 6.4.1

I've been trying for a while to get everything in order but I'm completely lost. All of my functions were previously deployed and working fine, but not anymore. When I try to deploy, none of the functions deploy properly. Every one fails and gives this same error:

> Deployment error.
>   Build failed: exit status 254
>   npm WARN lifecycle node@6.14.4~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) node@6.14.4 node installArchSpecificPackage /workspace/node_modules/.staging/node-378c0d58
>   functions@ /workspace
>   `-- apns@0.1.0` 
>   -- q@1.5.1
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-133-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "--global-style" "--production" "--fetch-retries=5" "--fetch-retry-factor=2" "--fetch-retry-mintimeout=1000" "install" "/workspace"
>   npm ERR! node v6.14.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/node/bin/node
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall chmod
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/workspace/node_modules/node/bin/node'
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/workspace/node_modules/node/bin/node'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /workspace/npm-debug.log

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's effectively a bug report and should be directed to Firebase email support. Please send the steps to reproduce this error to them.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Voting for the same, especially since it was reported as https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/313 a few days before